# ToDoList tutorial for XCode No Getter Method for read from property- OBJ C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've gone through the XCode app development tutorial a few times now and keep coming up with the same error.

source.ToDoItem gives the error "no getter method to read from property"

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  I can't seem to write a correct getter method and I can't find an example in the development tutorial to go off of.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
AddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
ToDoItem *item = source.ToDoItem;
if (item != nil) {
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

}
```

ToDoItem.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ToDoItem : NSObject

@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;

@end
```

ToDoItem.m

```
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@implementation ToDoItem

@end
```

ToDoListTableViewController

```
#import "ToDoListTableViewController.h"

#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@interface ToDoListTableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

@end

@implementation ToDoListTableViewController

- (void)loadInitialData {
    ToDoItem *item1 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = @"things";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
    ToDoItem *item2 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item2.itemName = @"Things to do with things";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];
    ToDoItem *item3 = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    item3.itemName = @"Write Ethics Paper";
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];

}

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    AddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    ToDoItem *item = source.ToDoItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadInitialData];

    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.toDoItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ToDoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    // Configure the cell...

    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    ToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
@end
```

and ToDoListTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ToDoItem.h"
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"

@interface ToDoListTableViewController : UITableViewController
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;

@end
```

AddToDoItemViewController.m

```
#import "AddToDoItemViewController.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"



@interface AddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;


@end

@implementation AddToDoItemViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
    }
    self.toDoItem = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];
    self.toDoItem.itemName = self.textField.text;
    self.toDoItem.completed = NO;
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}



@end
```

AddToDoItemViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@interface AddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController


@property ToDoItem *toDoItem;
@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;

@end
```

Comment: You don't seem to have shown `AddToDoItemViewController.h` which should be where the associated property is defined. You also don't look to be following naming conventions

Comment: Sorry about that, just added those two files. 
The naming convention discrepancies are a result of Apple's example code, do you have specifics on what I did wrong with naming and how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, "no getter method for read from property" is exactly the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AddToDoItemViewController` you have

```
@property ToDoItem *toDoItem;
```

but in the code you use it as:

```
ToDoItem *item = source.ToDoItem;
```

where it should be:

```
ToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
```

Note the naming convention. The class name starts with a capital letter and the property name starts with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these two lines:

```
@property NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL completed;
```

For this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemName;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL completed;
```

Comment: in ToDoItem.h or AddToDoItemViewController?

Comment: Ok, try to make it with @property ToDoItem *toDoItem;